# Dynamic component with customer injector pass @self dependency

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm dynamically creating FormControl's from a parent component like this:

```
  constructor(
    private _resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private _containerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private _injector: Injector,
    @Self() private _parentControl: NgControl
  ) { }

  ...

  createComponent() {
    this._component = this._containerRef.createComponent(
      this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(SomeComponent),
      0,
      this._injector // I know I need to do something here??
    );
  }
```

In `SomeComponent` I have the following, which works

```
constructor(public parentControl: NgControl) {
```

but I want to do this:

```
constructor(@Self() public parentControl: NgControl) {
```

How do I modify the injector (probably do an `Injector.create`?) to accomplish what I need?

Comment: so not 100% sure of this, but if you look at the api doc at https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent, you'll see that the injector param is described as 'The injector to use as the parent for the new component.'. 

Just curious why you want to try and make it work with @Self()?

Comment: @AbrahamAl-Dabbagh - thanks for the reply. That makes sense - so there's no way to modify the local injector, only the parent injector for dynamic components. The reason why I wanted to do this is because I wanted to use my component two ways - dynamically, and non-dynamically. When used non-dynamically, the dependency will be on the local injector, I wanted to make it work the same way dynamically. Instead, I'm going to just set the dependency as a property directly on the component instance when I'm instantiating dynamically. Kind of hacky, but the only way I can see doing it.

Comment: I would think that what you need should just work out of the box by injecting ngControl normally. If that didn't work, you could try using @Host, which I believe will first look at the component injector, then the parent injector.